# brew install postgresql (upgrade) error, could not link - dead links to old non-existent version

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

> Warning: Do not start deleting files manually in Terminal unless
>   you've tried everything else first. Manual deletion may caused
>   uninstall and install programs to crash.

This is QA style post, sharing my path to resolve the issue. I'm sure there are better ways

I picked up an older mac air and wanted to set it up for Ruby and Rails training. During the upgrade I had issues with installing postgresql:

```
➜  ~  brew install postgresql
....
==> Installing postgresql
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/postgresql-9.3.5.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/postgresql-9.3.5.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring postgresql-9.3.5.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
...
To reload postgresql after an upgrade:
    launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
Error: An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.3/include/server
Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.3/include/server
```

I'm installing postgresql 9.3.5, I couldn't care less about 9.2.3 not being found!

```
➜  ~  brew install postgresql
Warning: postgresql-9.3.5 already installed, it's just not linked
```

but postgres was still broken.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
brew update 
brew doctor
```

is always first steps.

to help finding files, update the files db

```
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

this is similar to updatedb on ubuntu and you might want to alias it.

then you may perform

```
locate postgresql
```

and learn more about where things are.

Chances are you made the mistake of deleting the files and folders just like me (sorry, that's a stupid thing to do). What I learn is that then I have a bunch of dead symlinks.

homebrew mostly use `/usr/`, more specifically `/usr/local/bin` and puts all source on `/usr/local/Cellar`, symlink local/bin to Cellar bin

what I did was to hunt down those dead symlinks and kill them over again. unlink.

move into the `/usr/local/bin` and others in the `/usr` and do

```
sudo find . -type l -exec test ! -e {} \; -delete
```

this test that the target of symlinks exists and delete if not.

To find symlinks in a folder and subfolders do

```
sudo ls -lR /usr | grep \^l
# and only those pointing to something postgresql:
sudo ls -lR /usr | grep \^l | grep postgresql
```

that'll get you a step further.

I couldn't even install wget, `brew install wget´ because of some`wgetrc`issue. I found that being a dead symlink`/usr/local/etc/wgetrc`

Having cleaned up the symlinks, my system works much better and finally postgresql installed as a charm

```
➜ brew uninstall postgresql
➜ brew install postgresql
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/postgresql-9.3.5.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/postgresql-9.3.5.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring postgresql-9.3.5.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
If builds of PostgreSQL 9 are failing and you have version 8.x installed,
you may need to remove the previous version first. See:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/issue/2510

To migrate existing data from a previous major version (pre-9.3) of PostgreSQL, see:
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/upgrading.html

When installing the postgres gem, including ARCHFLAGS is recommended:
  ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg

To install gems without sudo, see the Homebrew wiki.

To reload postgresql after an upgrade:
    launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
==> /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5/bin/initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5: 2927 files, 39M

# and in my project
➜ bundle
➜ rake db:create
➜ rake db:migrate
# YEAH!
```

Comment: You can also use `brew prune` to clean up dead symlinks.

Comment: Thanks @TimSmith. Hopefully those that try that approach and it helped them, will let us know. It sounds way simpler :)

Answer (score 13):

I had the similar problem but with another package. Turned out there had been a bunch of dead links pointing to the old version all other my file system. Here is what helped in my case:

1. Run `brew link <appname>` (e.g. `brew link postgress`);
2. If completed successfully then you are golden, otherwise proceed with the next step;
3. Take a look at the path in the error message (e.g. **/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.3/include/server**) transform the path by removing the **Cellar/<app name>/<version>** from it (e.g. **/usr/local/include/server**)
4. Find under that path all links referring to **Cellar/<app name>/<version>** and remove them;
5. Goto step 1.

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks for adding more useful instructions to this Q&A style post :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Yosemite 10.10.3.

My steps were:

1. Install latest OS updates
2. List item
3. Install updates from xCode
4. in terminal run command: brew install postgresql
5. in terminal run command: sudo brew link postgresql
6. in terminal run command: gem install pg -v '0.18.1'

then bundle install and it's done.

Comment: For anyone checking this answer in 2017:
- you cannot use sudo with brew any longer
- there is a typo in step 5 (link <SPACE> postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

I ran brew doctor and followed the relevant suggestions. In this case

```
Warning: The following directories do not exist:/usr/local/include
You should create these directories and change their ownership to your account.
  sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/include
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/include
```

After that, I was able to run brew link postgresql

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data >logfile 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Please explain what your statement is doing to help with the problem

Comment: It's a command from a postgresql doc. If it says that postgresql is already installed you could try to run it from the postgres directory and if it will be successful you will see a process pid of postgresql server

Answer (score -3):

'/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.21/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.6 start && brew services start postgresql' returned me postgre not installed

brew install postgresql
returned me not linked

brew services start postgresql
returned me root can not be found

psql postgres