# Brew cannot link postgresql OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

The steps I followed:

```
brew install postgresql
```

Installed it but couldn't link it

```
Error: An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.3/include/informix
Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.3/include/informix

(ve)Hermans-MacBook-Air: hermanstander$  brew config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
HEAD: e04275e113a52ad1e26e2973f6d29b508ca702be
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: quad-core 64-bit haswell
OS X: 10.10-x86_64
Xcode: 5.1.1
CLT: 6.0.0.0.1.1406926514
Clang: 5.1 build 503
X11: N/A
System Ruby: 2.0.0-481
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /Users/hermanstander/apps/foo/foo_app/ve/bin/python
Ruby: /usr/bin/rub
```

Answer (score 9):

Based on a hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075888/brew-install-postgresql-upgrade-error-could-not-link-dead-links-to-old-non?rq=1) that old symlinks can confuse `brew link`, please try `brew prune; brew link postgresql` and see if that resolves your issue.

9.3.3 is an old version of postgresql and I don't see the Homebrew revision you're using in the Homebrew git history? If you have `brew update`d recently, there is some discussion of this issue [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/29988#issuecomment-50511175). It's not obvious what's causing the issue (unless it's dead symlinks, discussed above) but it looks like `cd /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql; cp -r 9.3.5 9.3.3` will allow `brew link postgresql` to work, though that's kludgey.

If you haven't updated recently, please `brew rm postgresql; brew update` and try again. You should be installing 9.3.5.

(I don't suppose it's causing trouble here but, incidentally, running Homebrew with an active Python virtualenv is not supported.)

Comment: brew prune appears to no longer exist, I get `Error: Unknown command: prune`

Comment: As of 2020, there is no `brew prune`. Try `brew cleanup` instead.